# SubString a URL from the end?

Tags: java, substring

```
"http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/26189-abstract-color-background.jpg"
```

I want to substring this url so i get the image name
"26189-abstract-color-background.jpg"

How to do it?

Comment: Split the string with `\\`.

Comment: Start with [`String#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) and [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
String s = "http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/26189-abstract-color-background.jpg";
s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: Can you translate that into Java? ;)  BTW You need to add one to the index.

Comment: i've edit my post :), sr for this syntax. I'm .Neter ^^!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
String url = "http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/26189-abstract-color-background.jpg";
String file = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

or

```
String file = new URL(url).getFile();
```

I prefer the second, because even though it is a bit slower, it is much clearer and you might want other part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lastIndexOf()` with `substring()`.

```
String path = "http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/26189-abstract-color-background.jpg";

String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way of doing it is with regex where it can be accomplished with the following:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\/([^\\/]+)$").matcher(link);
if (m.find())
    fileName = m.group(1);
```

Where the regex means '/' followed by any number of non-'/' at the end of the string.

But if you want to use substring, it's easy to do as well with the following.

```
String fileName = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Comment: I suspect substring is more efficient that regex.  I would add a regex example any way so the OP can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
String x="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/26189-abstract-color-background.jpg";

x.substring(x.indexOf('2'))
```

Comment: What if you have a URL where the first letter of the file is not `2`? or the port or directory contains 2.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I answered to what he wanted in  his question

Comment: You could have just set `String s = "26189-abstract-color-background.jpg";` in that case.

Comment: "I want to substring this url
"
that is how he asked

Comment: *"that is how he asked"*  Please don't presume that a literal answer to a question is (necessarily) best.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree. In my experience, the OP has a requirement (sometimes missing from the question so you have to guess) for which he/she has attempted a solution but only got so far.  Often they will be happy with anything which solves their real requirement.  Unfortunately sometimes there is no real requirement ;)